# Storing dataview column values into array

Tags: c#, arrays, dataview

I have a dataview which is derived from a datasource which returns multiple rows and has multiple columns.

I would like to store all of the values of a particular column of the dataview into an array so I can compare them against a single value from another dataview.

The value from the dataview which returns a single value is written like the following, the datasource for this dataview only returns one result:

```
int priority;
DataView dvSelectedTask = (DataView)dsIPFromGV.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
priority = (int)dvSelectedTask.Table.Rows[0][3];
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Does it have to be an `array` or can you use another, perhaps more well-suited, type of [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ybcx56wz.aspx#bkmk_kindsofcollections)?

Comment: It doesn't matter really, I just need to be able to compare the value of one dataview result against all values in a column of another dataview.

Comment: Okay.  I asked only because you have to set the size of the array when you _intialize it_, whereas with a `List<>` for example, you don't.  I would suggest a `List<>` in all honesty.

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach statement with an array created would work for parsing the data.

Furthermore, I would recommend using different datatypes as Brian had mentioned.  Either maintaining the dataview or perhaps a List of some sort would be appropriate

```
string [] strArray = new strArray[dvSelectedTask.Length];
int index = 0;
foreach(DataRow dr in dvSelectedTask.Table.Rows)
{
    index++;
    str[index] = dr[0];
}
```